# Recommended practice for activating INotifyPropertyChanged in POCOs returned by Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've have some POCOs that inherit from a common business base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. 
I'm also using EF5 at the DAL. If i was to do a fetch for a single competitor object as below:

```
public ICompetitorCard Fetch(long id)
        {
            return this.Fetch<ContactCardContext, ICompetitorCard>(
               () => { return ContactCardContext.GetInstance(this); },
               ctx =>
               {
                   var query = from competitor in ctx.Competitors
                               where competitor.Id == id
                               select competitor;

                   return query.SingleOrDefault();
               }, "ICompetitorCard Fetch(long id) failed");
        }
```

I get back my CompetitorCard object nicely filled by EF5. The problem is I don't want notifications to fire  when loading from DAL. So typically I might set some kind of field that tracks whether the object has been initialised. That's easy to implement "normally" but since in this case EF is doing the loading I'm wondering what event/virtual method I need to hook into in order to set

```
IsInitialised = true;
```

such that thereafter property notifications fire. I suppose I could do something like:

```
ICompetitorCard card = query.SingleOrDefault();
if (card!=null){card.IsInitialised = true;}
return card;
```

But that seems overly verbose, breaks encapsulation and is a pain for collections etc. So for those handling their own implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged how are they managing this with EF5?

Comment: Is it fair to say its not POCO if its a derivation? :)

Comment: @MeirionHughes Very fair. I was thinking of the search terms people "seem" to use regarding the subject.

Comment: I wonder whether if would be better to handle this from the "loading the DAL" side rather than adding this logic into your data-objects. i.e. Deactivate Binding / event listeners. It is after all, not a data concern.

Comment: I thought `IsInitialised` was an external factor, not whether the object is instantiated

Comment: @MeirionHughes IsInitialised would be a private field to the object. Instantiation alone is enough because "presumably" EF instantiates the object with the default () constructor and then loads it's properties. So for my purposes IsInitialised would be (instantiated + loaded).... once thats done the object can start tracking it own state + firing events / validating / etc. What I dont want is object IsDirty = true or State=modified, just because it was loaded from the Db. In that case State=Unchanged or IsDirty=false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You "activate" `INotifyPropertyChanged` by subscribing to the event within the object and this cannot be done until the object has been instantiated.

Within your object you do not raise a change event unless there is a subscriber.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) for more info.

---

UPDATE:

You can subscribe to the `ObjectMaterialized` event of the `ObjectContext` to mark your objects as loaded. Something like this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
this.ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized;
```

implement your function

```
ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e).
```

`EventArgs` will give you your object, which has just been materialised.

Comment: Yes the mistake Ive made is in tying the question to INotifyPropertyChanged and that has produced discussion around the binding angle. So if I was tracking object state, (IsDirty) obviously that would be internal to the object not an external subscriber. If a property is changed  then if (this.IsInitialised) {IsDirty=true;} otherwise do nothing. But how to determine this.IsInitialised if EF is doing the loading and without adding in the code as per the 3rd code section in my question for every fetch and fill method across the DAL. At this stage its looking like an extension method of some sort

Comment: @rism I can't see why the object would need to know if it was 'dirty' as it should not be in a position to do anything about it and anything else that needs to know would subscribe (assuming it's SOLID). You can subscribe to the `ObjectMaterialized` event of the `ObjectContext` to mark your objects as loaded - see my update.

Comment: Ah brilliant an adapter. I'm using DbContext which inherits from object and no such event. tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, your poco types used for entity framework would not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you would map the values of the properties you require to a new type which is then bound to the view (which does implement INotifyPropertyChanged)... depending on your architecture that would either be a business object or perhaps even a view model.

This is useful in many scenarios, especially as your database will rarely perfectly represent your UI perfectly.

Comment: Thats a great point but in this case the CompetitorCard is a near perfect match. I might have tied the question to closely to the problem at hand. I guess Im more generally interested in knowing how do you know that EF has finished loading your object....without  doing an intermediate reference as above.

Comment: For the moment it closely matches but databases change, you also loose the benefit of being able to do projection and ask only for the information you require... I also don't understand... the problem you have is only because you are trying to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your DTO's... you know that EF has finished loading your class because it gets returned fully loaded... you would then usually map the properties you require to your new type (which would notify of changes). What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, you're right. I'll concede it's a poorly conceived /  lazy architecture. So INotifyPropertyChanged aside, I still wonder how we know that EF is "done" doing it's thing.

Comment: Its done when the type is returned to you? ... If you ask for a record in the database.. when the poco that represents that record is returned to you from your query... it's done. I'm confused as to what more you would like?

Comment: Ok so say I have a business objects that needs business rule validation upon the change of a property. That change could occur through interaction with other business objects, not just the UI. So some business objects need to run business rules in the event of property changes but its wasteful to run the rules if the object is loaded from DB. It would have been validated prior to persistence so we can assume its valid. So I dont want to trigger validation after the load from DB/EF but once the object is loaded with data, I then want to turn on validation for the remainder of its lifetime.